# decodeAudioData crashes iOS browsers

Tags: ios, safari, web-audio-api

Here is an existing site that experiences this issue. I tried on both Google Chrome and Safari on iPad and iPhone. All crashed. There is no problem at all on Android devices.

[kevvv.in/mix](http://kevvv.in/mix)

I really want to know why iOS performs so badly. Is there a workaround?